# Using the Limit definition to find the derivative of $e^x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was wondering how we could use the limit definition

$$ \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

to find the derivative of $e^x$, I get to a point where I do not know how to simplify the indeterminate $\frac{0}{0}$. Below is what I have already done

$$\begin{align}
&\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \\
&\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{x+h}-e^x}{h} \\
&\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^x (e^h-1)}{h} \\
&e^x \cdot \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^h-1}{h}
\end{align}$$

Where can I go from here? Because, the $\lim$ portion reduces to indeterminate when $0$ is subbed into $h$.

Comment: How do you define $e$?

Comment: @AdamSaltz $e$ as in euler's constant?

Comment: @julien Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "the function of $e^x$". Can you please clarify?

Comment: @julien I don't think I understand what it means to define a function. Do you mean if it is an exponential function or a one to one function?

Comment: Some people define the exponential $e^x$ as the unique solution of the ode: $y'=y$ and $y(0)=1$. For these people, no needto prove that $\frac{d}{dx}e^x=e^x$. It holds by definition. Now given your title, there are I think two possibilities: $e^x=\lim_n \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}$, or $e^x=\lim_n\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$.

Comment: @julien oh! That is what you mean, sorry about that. I know about the former but how can you do it with the latter $e^x=\lim_n\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: Be careful, the exponent is $n$, not $\frac{1}{n}$, in this formula. Is it what your question really is? How do we do with the limity binomial formula? If so, you should add that to your question.

Comment: You simply have to somehow know the value of $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^h -1}{h}$ to do it this way.

Comment: @gekkostate: Why don't you use the formula $\exp(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^\infty \dfrac{x^i}{i!}$? Then $\dfrac{\exp(h)-1}{h}=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty \dfrac{h^{i-1}}{i!}$. And noting that each limit exists we can evaluate the limit easily.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Sometimes one *defines* $e$ as the (unique) number for which $$\tag 1 \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^h-1}{h}=1$$

In fact, there are two possible directions.

$(i)$ Start with the logarithm. You'll find out it is continuous monotone increasing on $\Bbb R_{>0}$, and it's range is $\Bbb R$. It follows $\log x=1$ for some $x$. We define this (unique) $x$ to be $e$. Some elementary properties will pop up, and one will be $$\tag 2 \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}=1$$

Upon defining $\exp x$ as the inverse of the logarithm, and after some rules, we will get to defining exponentiation of $a>0\in \Bbb R$ as $$a^x:=\exp(x\log a)$$

In said case, $e^x=\exp(x)$, as we expected. $(1)$ will then be an immediate consequence of $(2)$.

$(ii)$ We might define $$e=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1 {k!}$$ (or the equivalent Bernoulli limit). Then, we may define $$\exp x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$$ Note $$\tag 3 \exp 1=e$$

We define the $\log$ as the inverse of the exponential function. We may derive certain properties of $\exp x$. The most important ones would be $$\exp(x+y)=\exp x\exp y$$ $$\exp'=\exp$$ $$\exp 0 =1$$

In particular, we have that $\log e=1$ by. We might then define general exponentiation yet again by $$a^x:=\exp(x\log a)$$

Note then that again $e^x=\exp x$. We can prove $(1)$ easily recurring to the series expansion we used.

---

**ADD** As for the definition of the logarithm, there are a few ones. One is $$\log x=\int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}$$

Having defined exponentiation of real numbers using rationals by $$a^x=\sup\{a^r:r\in\Bbb Q\wedge r<x\}$$

we might also define $$\log x=\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{x^k-1}{k}$$

In any case, you should be able to prove that

$$\tag 1 \log xy = \log x +\log y $$
$$\tag 2 \log x^a = a\log x  $$
$$\tag 3 1-\dfrac 1 x\leq\log x \leq x-1 $$
$$\tag 4\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\log(1+x)}{x}=1 $$
$$\tag 5\dfrac{d}{dx}\log x = \dfrac 1 x$$

What you want is a direct consequence of either $(4)$ or $(5)$, or of the first sentence in my post.

---

**ADD** We can prove that for $x \geq 0$ $$\lim\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n=\exp x$$ from definition $(ii)$.

First, note that $${n\choose k}\frac 1{n^k}=\frac{1}{{k!}}\frac{{n\left( {n - 1} \right) \cdots \left( {n - k + 1} \right)}}{{{n^k}}} = \frac{1}{{k!}}\left( {1 - \frac{1}{n}} \right)\left( {1 - \frac{2}{n}} \right) \cdots \left( {1 - \frac{{k - 1}}{n}} \right)$$

Since all the factors to the rightmost are $\leq 1$, we can claim $${n\choose k}\frac{1}{{{n^k}}} \leqslant \frac{1}{{k!}}$$

It follows that $${\left( {1 + \frac{x}{n}} \right)^n}=\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {{n\choose k}\frac{{{x^k}}}{{{n^k}}}}  \leqslant \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\frac{{{x^k}}}{{k!}}} $$

It follows that **if** the limit on the left exists, $$\lim {\left( {1 + \frac{x}{n}} \right)^n} \leqslant \lim \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\frac{{{x^k}}}{{k!}}}  = \exp x$$

Note that the sums in $$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {{n\choose k}\frac{{{x^k}}}{{{n^k}}}} $$

are always increasing, which means that for $m\leq  n$

$$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^m {{n\choose k}\frac{{{x^k}}}{{{n^k}}}}\leq  \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {{n\choose k}\frac{{{x^k}}}{{{n^k}}}}$$

By letting $n\to\infty$, since $m$ is fixed on the left side, and $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{1}{{k!}}\left( {1 - \frac{1}{n}} \right)\left( {1 - \frac{2}{n}} \right) \cdots \left( {1 - \frac{{k - 1}}{n}} \right) = \frac{1}{{k!}}$$

we see that **if** the limit exists, then for each $m$, we have $$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^m {\frac{{{x^k}}}{{k!}}}  \leqslant \lim {\left( {1 + \frac{x}{n}} \right)^n}$$

But then, taking $m\to\infty$ $$\exp x = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{m \to \infty } \sum\limits_{k = 0}^m {\frac{{{x^k}}}{{k!}}}  \leqslant \lim {\left( {1 + \frac{x}{n}} \right)^n}$$

It follows that **if** the limit exists $$\eqalign{
  & \exp x \leqslant \lim_{n\to\infty} {\left( {1 + \frac{x}{n}} \right)^n}  \cr 
  & \exp x \geqslant \lim_{n\to\infty} {\left( {1 + \frac{x}{n}} \right)^n} \cr}$$ which means $$\exp x = \lim_{n\to\infty} {\left( {1 + \frac{x}{n}} \right)^n}$$ Can you show the limit exists?

The case $x<0$ follows now from $$\displaylines{
  {\left( {1 - \frac{x}{n}} \right)^{ - n}} = {\left( {\frac{n}{{n - x}}} \right)^n} \cr 
   = {\left( {\frac{{n - x + x}}{{n - x}}} \right)^n} \cr 
   = {\left( {1 + \frac{x}{{n - x}}} \right)^n} \cr} $$

using the squeeze theorem with $\lfloor n-x\rfloor$, $\lceil n-x\rceil$, and the fact $x\to x^{-1}$ is continuous. We care only for terms $n>\lfloor x\rfloor$ to make the above meaningful.

**NOTE** If you're acquainted with $\limsup$ and $\liminf$; the above can be put differently as $$\eqalign{
  & \exp x \leqslant \lim \inf {\left( {1 + \frac{x}{n}} \right)^n}  \cr 
  & \exp x \geqslant \lim \sup {\left( {1 + \frac{x}{n}} \right)^n} \cr} $$ which means $$\lim \inf {\left( {1 + \frac{x}{n}} \right)^n} = \lim \sup {\left( {1 + \frac{x}{n}} \right)^n}$$ and proves the limit exists and is equal to $\exp x$.

Comment: What is $\text{exp}$? and $\text{sup}$?

Comment: What a job, Peter, +1. It remains $\lim (1+x/n)^n$...

Comment: @gekkostate $\exp$ stand for the "exponential" function. One doesn't really *know* beforehand that $\exp x=e^x$, but it is a very easy thing to see as I'm showing you. The "word" $\sup$ stands for the "supremum" of a set. In the case of real numbers, we define the supremum of a set $A\subseteq \Bbb R$ (if it exists) to be the (unique) number with the following properties:

Comment: $(i)$ For any number $a\in A$, $a\leq x$. That is, $x$ is what we call an upper bound for the elements of $a$. As an example, $2$ is an upper bound for $[0,1)$, because for any $x\in[0,1)$, $x\leq 2$.
$(ii)$ If $y$ is any other number with the above property $x\leq y$. That is, $x$ is the least of all the upper bounds. 

That is why we usually call $\sup$ the "least upper bound" of $A$, and write $\operatorname{lub}(A)$. 
${}$
*Question*: What is $\sup [0,1)$? A tougher one: what is $\sup \{r\in \Bbb Q:r^2<2\}$?

Comment: @AJMansfield You're supposed to let the OP answer that!!! >8(

Comment: The main issue with the Wikipedia definition of the LUB is, in my opinion, is that for sets that are not subsets of the real numbers, the need for the LUB itself to be within the subset is more ambiguous, and I was also working with more general sets than just the real number subsets.

Comment: @AJMansfield The notion of lub and of glb is applicable to any partial ordered set $S$.

Comment: @julien If you wish so...

Comment: @PeterTamaroff I know that, that's my favorite subject in math.  Unfortunately, I haven't really had much opportunity to learn it, as I am only a junior in high school.

Comment: @julien My job here is done.

Comment: I hope the OP appreciates. I do!

Comment: @gekkostate Let $e^h-1=u$. Then $u\to 0\iff e^h-1\to 0$. The limit then states, since $h=\log(u+1)$, $$\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{u}{\log(1+u)}=1$$ which we can prove using the definition of the logarithm I gave you.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff 5 seconds, after I posted the comment (hence ,the deletion), I realized that exactly that! Thanks for the quick reply though! I really appreciate the time and effort you have put into this post.

Answer (score 18):

First prove that $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\ln(h+1)}{h}=1$. The switch of $\ln$, $\lim$ is possible because $f(x)=\ln x$, $x>0$ is continuous.

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\ln\left( (1+h)^{\frac{1}{h}} \right)=\ln\lim_{h\to 0}\left( (1+h)^{\frac{1}{h}} \right)=\ln e = 1$$

Now let $u=e^h-1$. We know $h\to 0\iff u\to 0$.

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^h-1}{h}=\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{u}{\ln(u+1)}=1$$

Answer (score 8):

If you have have a proof for $\displaystyle\frac{d\ln x}{dx}$, you can always prove $\displaystyle\frac{de^x}{dx}$ by taking $\displaystyle\frac{d\ln e^x}{dx}$ using chain rule.

First, we know: $$\frac{d\ln e^x}{dx} = \frac{dx}{dx} = 1$$

Second, using chain rule:

$$\frac{d\ln e^x}{dx} = \frac{1}{e^x}\frac{de^x}{dx} $$ Using the fact that we know both sides equal $1$, then:

$$\frac{1}{e^x}\frac{de^x}{dx} = 1  $$ Multiplying both sides by $e^x$ gives:

$$\frac{de^x}{dx}= e^x$$

Comment: Why was this downvoted? lol. seems elegant

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803155/how-to-show-that-ex-is-differentiable?noredirect=1#comment1660234_803155

Answer (score 4):

The discovery of the constant $e$ is credited to Jacob Bernoulli in 1683 who attempted to find the value of the following expression (which is equal to $e$):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}{\left(1+\frac1n\right)}^n.$$

Alternatively, we can substitute $n=\frac1h$ to obtain:

$$e=\lim_{h\to0}(1+h)^{1/h}.$$

Substitute this limit into your expression to get:

$$e^x\lim_{h\to0}\frac{{\left((1+h)^{1/h}\right)}^h-1}h$$

$$=e^x\lim_{h\to0}\frac{{(1+h)}-1}h$$

$$=e^x.$$

Answer (score 3):

Just to prove this in a new way, using a specialized case:

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{ah}-1}{h}$$

where a is any number

Here's how I did it:

$$e= \lim_{n \to \infty} \Big(1 + \frac{1}{n} \Big)^{n}$$

Recognize that $1/n$ is just an infinitesimal, and $n$ is just a representation of infinity. By doing this, we can redefine $e$ in terms of $h$.

$$e= \lim_{h \to 0} \Big(1 + h \Big)^{\frac{1}{h}}$$

Plug this back in:

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{ah}-1}{h} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{((1+h)^{1/h})^h-1}{h} $$

$$= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{((1+h)^{1/h})^{ah}-1}{h} $$

$$= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{(1+h)^a-1}{h} $$

Binomial theorem:

$$= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\Big(\dbinom{a}{0}1^ah^0+\dbinom{a}{1}1^{a-1}h^1+ ... +\dbinom{a}{a-1}1^{1}h^{a-1}+\dbinom{a}{a}1^{0}h^a\Big)- 1}{h}$$

Getting rid of all of those pesky ones:

$$= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\Big(\dbinom{a}{0}h^0+\dbinom{a}{1}h^1+ ... +\dbinom{a}{a-1}h^{a-1}+\dbinom{a}{a}h^a\Big)-1}{h}$$

The term $\dbinom{a}{0}h^0$ is equal to one, allowing us to cancel the stuff at the end.

$$= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\Big(\dbinom{a}{1}h^1+ ... +\dbinom{a}{a-1}h^{a-1}+\dbinom{a}{a}h^a\Big)}{h}$$

We can now  simplify the limit.
$$= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \Big(\dbinom{a}{1}+ ... +\dbinom{a}{a-1}h^{a-2}+\dbinom{a}{a}h^{a-1}\Big)$$

We can now evaluate the limit. Everything other than the first term is multiplied by h and becomes 0, leaving us with

$$= \dbinom{a}{1} = a$$

Meaning $$\frac{e^{ah}-1}{h} = a$$. However, when a = 1, the first limit also equals 1.

Answer (score 2):

To show the equivalence of the characterizations $e = \lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + \frac 1n)^n$ and $e^x = \frac d{dx} e^x$, assume the latter and prove that $\ln'(x) = \frac 1x$.

$$
1 = \ln'(1)
= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac {ln(1+x)-\ln(1)}x
= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac 1x \ln(1+x)
= \lim_{x \to 0} \ln\left((1+x)^{\frac 1x}\right)
$$

Then, by the continuity of $\exp(x)$:

$$
e = e^1 = e^{\lim_{x \to 0} \ln\left((1+x)^{\frac 1x}\right)} = \lim_{x \to 0} e^{\ln\left((1+x)^{\frac 1x}\right)} = (1+x)^{\frac 1x} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+ \frac 1n\right)^n
$$

Since the limit is *well*-defined, the characterizations must be equivalent.

Comment: This is a clever answer but how would you know ln(1)=0 if we're assuming the new definition of e?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** :for one definition of e
$$e=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac1n)^n$$
and use the Binomial expansion

Comment: Could you elaborate?