# Is it true that $ e $ is equal to this?

Tags: real-numbers, irrational-numbers

Is it true that

$$ e^{ab} =  \lim_{n\to \infty}  \Bigl(1 +  \frac{a}{n}\Bigr) ^ {bn} $$

I remember seeing that forumla somewhere, and wasn't sure it was correct. Or if I don't remember it correctly.

If it is correct, can anyone send me a reference to a proof? or something that shows why it is correct

Comment: If you already know about the exponential function, evaluate this as an indeterminate form $1^\infty$.  Your calculus textbook should discuss such indeterminate forms.

Comment: The limit definition of $e$ is mentioned in its [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)). It's discussed in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359023/using-the-limit-definition-to-find-the-derivative-of-ex), and also proved [here](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/ma122/elimit.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition it is $$e^{a} =  \lim_{n\to \infty}  \Bigl(1 +  \frac{a}{n}\Bigr) ^ {n}.$$ And thus

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}  \Bigl(1 +  \frac{a}{n}\Bigr) ^ {bn}=\lim_{n\to \infty}  \Bigl(\Bigl(1 +  \frac{a}{n}\Bigr) ^ {n}\Bigr)^b=\Bigl(\lim_{n\to \infty}  \Bigl(\Bigl(1 +  \frac{a}{n}\Bigr) ^ {n}\Bigr)^b=(e^a)^b=e^{ab}.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :** Try to expand $e^{ab}$ by Taylor's Series Expansion. See what you've got !!